# Getting a No Route Match on Edit Proposals Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is my code in the view, just calling to the edit proposal path

`<%= link_to "Edit this Proposal", edit_idea_proposal_path %>`

This is my code in the Proposals Controller. I clearly have an "Edit" action, so why is it giving me a route error for Edit?

```
def create
    @idea = Idea.find(params[:idea_id])
    @proposal = @idea.proposals.create(params[:proposal])

    if @proposal.save
        flash[:success] = "Thanks for the Proposal!"
        redirect_to idea_proposals_url(@idea)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end 

def edit
    @idea = Idea.find(params[:idea_id])
    @proposal = @idea.proposals.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @idea = Idea.find(params[:idea_id])
    @proposal = @idea.proposals.find(params[:id])

    if @proposal.update_attributes(params[:proposal])
        redirect_to idea_proposals_url(@idea)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a route for your edit action in your `config/routes.rb` file, and if so, how is that route nested? If it's directly in a `resources :proposals` block, then the route should be `edit_proposal_path`, since you say your controller is called `ProposalsController`.

Comment: It is directly nested, but edit_proposal_path doesn't work either. When I run rake routes it even says that the Edit path exists at edit_idea_proposal GET    /ideas/:idea_id/proposals/:id/edit(.:format) proposals#edit...could have something to do with the Edit form or view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I needed to change the code in my view from:

```
<%= link_to "Edit this Proposal", edit_idea_proposal_path %>
```

To:

```
<%= link_to "Edit this Proposal", edit_idea_proposal_path(@idea, proposal) %>
```